# {{ filter_values() }} is not working on Apache Superset

Tags: mysql, jinja2, apache-superset

My SQL query is

```sql
SELECT count(ce.id) 
FROM course_enrollments ce
LEFT JOIN course_batches as cb ON cb.id = ce.course_batch_id
WHERE cb.bn_title IN ('title1') AND ce.course_completeness=100.00
AND ce.created_at between '2021-7-01' AND '2022-3-14'
```

I updated this query for filtering as

```sql
SELECT count(ce.id) 
FROM course_enrollments ce
LEFT JOIN course_batches as cb ON cb.id = ce.course_batch_id
WHERE cb.bn_title IN {{ filter_values('title')|where_in }} AND ce.course_completeness=100.00
AND ce.created_at between '2021-7-01' AND '2022-3-14'
```

But getting an error like this

```
Unexpected error
Error: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{{ filter_values('title')|where_in }}\n     AND ce.course_completeness=100.00\n   ' at line 6")
```

Syntax {{ filter_values() }} is not working in my apache superset. How can I solve this? 
I am using mysql database and connected it to apache superset.

Comment: This SQL is invalid on its own. It looks like you're trying to use some sort of database library. What function are you passing this SQL to?

Comment: @SimonBrahan The SQL is valid, WHERE cb.bn_title IN ('title1') is same as WHERE cb.bn_title='title1'. But I want to pass {{ filter_values() }} for filtering in apache superset

Comment: The SQL is not valid. It says so in the error, and shows you where. This SQL-ish statement *might* be *nearly* valid in a certain database library, but we can't help you unless we know what library you're using and how you're calling it. Can you add that information to your question?

Comment: I tried this https://preset.io/blog/intro-jinja-templating-apache-superset/

Answer (score 1):

Check if your Superset setup has the Jinja templates allowed (feature flag ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING needs to be set to true in superset/config.py, or in superset_config.py in the root directory).